# Coudn't click sign in or settext in in this page : https://candidates.acrolinx.sh/webchecker/

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I try this but it is not working:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='signinOpenBrowserButton submitButton']")).click();
```

Comment: I recognize that this is your first question, so just some tips in advance. Could you maybe add a bit more detail to your question? What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried so far?

Comment: "Not working" isn't clear... edit your question and post the actual error message or if there is no error, more details on what isn't working. Also add the HTML of the element you are trying to click along with some of the surrounding elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are nested `iframe` you need to switch to `iframe` first then you will able to access the button element.

Try below code.

```
 driver.get("https://candidates.acrolinx.sh/webchecker/");
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
    if (driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size()>0)
            {
                driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).get(0));
                if (driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size()>0)
                {
                    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).get(0));
                }
            }

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='signinOpenBrowserButton submitButton']"))).click();
```

Comment: Hiii , The same problem for " set text in left side"  ! How it will be work ! thanks

Comment: As I have mentioned check if there any iframe or nested iframes are their and if then you need to switch it first.However It will be better if you post a new question and elaborate what you are after on that post.Thanks.

Comment: this is the code in the same page ! I just want to set text in this page: